# Font-spacing problems in Konsole terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, fonts, konsole

Recently the font-spacing in my terminal changed. Some letters are overlapped by others and the entire line shifts and wiggles, when I move the cursor around. I posted an image below. Have a look at line 20 for example. As I move the cursor from the beginning of the line, the blank space behind the cursor gets bigger. Also note that letters are blocked as in line 19 (It's supposed to say PROMPT) and line 11 and 16 (autoload). This also happens in the shell and is not a problem of Emacs.

[image: image explaining fontspacing]

Any help on the problem is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Ben, the results of your research apply to virtual consoles while your problem is in relation to Konsole which is a terminal emulator that runs as an X-windows application. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console

Comment: Thank you! I changed the font in Konsole and fixed the problem.
Appearently this is a bug (https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215937), but some fonts are not affected.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. It might be worth writing that as a self-answer, accepting it and then editing your question to remove the console-related research. That way other users with the same issue could find this question-and-answer and benefit from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments by Anthony Geoghegan it was a Problem of the program `Konsole`. I found this is a [known bug](http://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215937), but some fonts are not affected. In `Konsole` I changed the font using
`Settings -> Edit current profile -> Appearance`.
The font `DejaVu Sans Mono` worked for me.

Thanks for the help in the comments!

(I deleted the part about changing the terminal-font in the original question as it has nothing to do with the error in `Konsole`)